# Change the value of multiple dynamically PHP generated text-boxes using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated-co

I have generated multiple text boxes using PHP with `name="student[<?php echo $StudentID ; ?>]"`.

Now on a button click i want to change the value of all these text boxes using jquery.

How do i do this ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/#attributevalue), to look for `student[` at the beginning of the name attribute:

```
$('input[name^="student["]').val('the new value');
```

It's probably unnecessary to include the `[` at the end, and `name^="student"` will be sufficient, assuming you don't have other inputs with names like `student_name` or the like.

```
// If no conflicting named inputs, use
$('input[name^="student"]').val('the new value');
```

Comment: You probably better add `'` around your selectors

Comment: @Michael : but sir, if i have some other elements also starting with name 'student...' , then what would i do? shall i have to use a foreach loop to loop all the Student IDs and then do this :------------: $('input[name="student[<?php echo $StudentID ; ?>]").val('new value');

Comment: @sqlchild Then my first example should work, using the partial selector `student[`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="student[]"></input>
<input type="text" name="student[]"></input>
<input type="text" name="student[]"></input>

<button id="button">Change</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('input[name^="student"]').val('some value ');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cpTgk/1/)

Comment: The names include a PHP-supplied id inside the `[]`. `name="student[<?php echo $StudentID ; ?>]`

Comment: @Michael yeah, I saw that the question was changed after I posted the answer, updated now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply add a class that is unique to all of those text boxes (i.e. changableTextBox) and then select it with that and change them all at once. It's also helpful for the future if you need to adjust some styling on all of them at once. Just declare that class in CSS and you're styling.

```
<input type="text" class="changeableStudentTextBox" id="student[11]" />
<input type="text" class="changeableStudentTextBox" id="student[23]" />
<input type="text" class="changeableStudentTextBox" id="student[45]" />
<input type="text" class="changeableStudentTextBox" id="student[66]" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#button').click( function() { $('.changeableStudentTextBox').val('hi!'); });
</script>
```